# How can I return the FIbonacci sequence using an int return type method without using recursion?

Tags: java, methods, fibonacci, return-type

I'm trying to create a method in Java that prints the fib series up to the number passed to the method. My issue is that I'm required to use an **int** return type to return the series and I **cannot use recursion**.

## My First Idea

My original idea was like shown. Which works just fine. It takes an argument of type **int** and returns **void** simply printing the numbers as they are calculated.

```java
public void fibonacci(int num) {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 1;
      

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        a = b;
        b = c;
        c = a + b;
        System.out.print(c + ", ");
    }
}
```

## What The Question Asks For

The code below shows what I was tasked to do. It asked for a method that takes an argument of type **int** and returns type **int**.

```java
public int fibonacci(int num) {
   
    //some code...

    return x; //This is what confuses me. I know this isn't right.
}
```

To me this just seems impractical and maybe even impossible to use an int return type. I'm wondering if anyone knows a way this is possible.

Expected Output:

```java
//Method call in driver class.
fibonacci(5);

//This would print to console.
1, 1, 2, 3, 5
```

Comment: You can’t return a series of ints with a single int by definition. What are you actually supposed to return? If you’re just supposed to print the series then add some prints.

Comment: Theoretically, in my driver class if I declare fibonacci(5), It should print "1,1,2,3,5". I know how strange this sounds that's why I'm wondering if it was a mistake on their part because it just doesn't seem possible to me either.

Comment: @MauricioFloresJr. No. Use a loop. `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { System.out.println(fibonacci(i)); }`

Comment: Unclear what you are trying to do. One option to clarify is to show recursive solution that you seem to have...

Comment: I had tried using that earlier and it gave me the last number of the series. I tried it again just now and for some reason it's returning the last number of the series as many times as the number given in the argument. I'll try to get a solution using your solution. @ElliottFrisch

Comment: My apologies @AlexeiLevenkov, I was given a task to create a method using the int return type. It is expected to somehow print the numbers in the sequence up to the number provided by the user. I'm trying to understand if maybe the int return type was a mistake on their part, or if maybe there's a way to get the same result as what I had done with the void return type. I understand it may be confusing and I apologize but that's exactly what was asked of me and I am just as confused.

Comment: I don't think SO can help you with that - we don't know what is expected from your assignment - asking whoever gave the assignment would be much better route.

Comment: Understood. I was just branching out to see if maybe someone had the answer that I was not familiar with. Thank you for your time. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the equation `[(h)^a - (j)^a] * [1/sqrt(5)]`.

- `'a'` is fibonacci number wanted
- `'h'` is [1 + sqrt(5)] / 2
- `'j'` is [1 -    sqrt(5)] / 2

```
public static int returnFibonacci(int a) {

  double firstTerm; // calculate h

  double secondTerm; //calculate j

  double fib; //calculate 1/sqrt(5) with firstTerm and secondTerm

}
```